# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit error starting using ssl

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I'm trying to connect with rabbitmq from aws (AmazonMQ) using Spring cloud Stream, and spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit using ssl, but I get an error when starting the application, I don't need to import certificates from aws, because they are public certificates, theoretically it would be a simple setting of ssl.enabled: true.
But using only spring-boot-starter-amqp dependency works.

My yml config:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: b-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    username: xxxxxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    port: 5671
    ssl:
      verify-hostname: false
      validate-server-certificate: false
      enabled: true
      algorithm: TLSv1.2
```

Spring-Boot 3.1.2,
Spring Cloud 2022.0.4,
Java 17

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry'
    defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitHealthContributor' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]:Signature Parse error: expected a class type
    Remaining input: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitHealthContributor' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Signature Parse error: expected a class type
    Remaining input: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1516) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Signature Parse error: expected a class type
    Remaining input: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1516) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: expected a class type
    Remaining input: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:124) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:301) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassSignature(SignatureParser.java:213) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassSig(SignatureParser.java:156) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.parse(ClassRepository.java:57) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.parse(ClassRepository.java:41) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.GenericDeclRepository.<init>(GenericDeclRepository.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.<init>(ClassRepository.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.make(ClassRepository.java:70) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInfo(Class.java:3263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getTypeParameters(Class.java:962) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.sharedToGenericString(Executable.java:165) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.toGenericString(Method.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.doWithMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:260) ~[spring-integration-core-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$4(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-integration-core-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:366) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-integration-core-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the error message this seems to be related to this bug in JDK 17 and later: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8282241

It was fixed in JDK 19 and backported to JDK 17.0.5 accoring to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8283597

So upgrading your JDK to at least version 17.0.5 might fix your issue.

Comment: It takes a bit of time to setup everything to test that sorry for the late response.